# sequelize compare date with date-timestamp

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, express, sequelize.js

my simple use case is I pass a `date` and try to compare that with the default `createdAt` column.

```
where: {
                createdAt: {
                    $eq: date
                }
            }
```

and my date is a string like this `date = '2018-12-12'`

The problem here is sequlize not compare only the date. But it does add time 00:00:00 to my date and then compare.
So the query sequlize generate is like this.

```
WHERE `redeem_points`.`createdAt` = '2018-11-02 00:00:00';
```

**What I deserved**

```
WHERE `redeem_points`.`createdAt` = '2018-11-02';
```

How do I achieve this using sequlize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would want something more like:

```
{
  where: {
    createdAt: { [Op.like]: `${date}%`, },
  }
}
```

Which would give SQL syntax like (note the wildcard):

```
WHERE createdAt LIKE '2018-11-02%'
```

[Operators](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators) can give you a broad range of SQL syntax equivalents, additionally I think the shorthand you are using is deprecated so I subbed in the `Op` syntax you might need that as `sequelize.Op` if you aren't destructuring your variables.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do it like

`createdAt:{[Op.between]:[moment().startOf("day").toDate(),moment().endOd("day").toDate()]}`

Answer (score 0):

I have used a [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) lib, but of course, you can get the start and end of the day using the JS functionality. you also need to check timezone.

```
let condition = {};

// For the case when you want to get a  data for the specific date
// if (date) {
//   condition.createdAt = {
//     [Op.and]: [
//       {
//         [Op.gte]: moment(date)
//           .startOf("day")
//           .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]"),
//       },
//       {
//         [Op.lte]: moment(date)
//           .endOf("day")
//           .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]"),
//       },
//     ],
//   };
// }

// If you want to get a data for the current day
condition.createdAt = {
  [Op.and]: [
    {
      [Op.gte]: moment().startOf("day").toDate(),
    },
    {
      [Op.lte]: moment().endOf("day").toDate(),
    },
  ],
};

ActivityLog.findAll({
  where: condition,
});
```